# How to get BLOCK I/O and NET I/O inside a container

Tags: docker

I want to get docker stats inside a container. We cant use docker stats command inside container . So ,I want to use cat /sys/fs/cgroup. How to get BLOCK I/O and NET I/O values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Measuring BLOCK I/O

The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/#metrics-from-cgroups-memory-cpu-block-io) describes how to do this. Essentially, inside the container, we have access to our cgroup. cgroups can be used to track how much block I/O is being done.

You read the file `/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/blkio.throttle.io_service_bytes`. This file will look like this:

```
8:0 Read 20201472
8:0 Write 14065664
8:0 Sync 21794816
8:0 Async 12472320
8:0 Discard 0
8:0 Total 34267136
253:0 Read 20201472
253:0 Write 14065664
253:0 Sync 21794816
253:0 Async 12472320
253:0 Discard 0
253:0 Total 34267136
Total 68534272
```

I found that the total figure at the bottom double-counts the block I/O being done, but you can use the two lines at the top to figure out total read/write.

I have verified that this works from inside a container.

### Measuring NET I/O

You can use `/proc/net/dev` to get network stats inside the container. That file looks like this:

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth0: 9620619    6480    0    0    0     0          0         0   253570    3808    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

You'll need to parse out the "Receive bytes" and "Transmit bytes" fields. Here's an example of how to do this in Awk:

```
cat /proc/net/dev | awk '/eth0/{print "RX Bytes " $2 "\nTX Bytes " $10}'
```

I have verified that this works from inside a container.

Comment: Looks like they are going down to the network device to gather the interface statistics down in the libnetwork code. You can see those interface stats by looking at `cat /proc/net/dev` inside the container.

Comment: @BMitch Ah, I see now! Thank you for the pointer, that was bugging me.

Comment: How to getCPU % using cat /sys/fs/cgroup @NickODell

Comment: @chitra That seems like a new question. Why don't you post it as a new question, and send me a link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63241098/how-to-get-cpu-inside-a-container . This is the link of the question @NickODell