# How to get CPU % inside a container

Tags: docker

I want to get docker stats inside a container. We cant use docker stats command inside container . So ,I want to use cat /sys/fs/cgroup. How to get CPU%.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways of doing this. Most methods of measuring CPU usage which work outside of a container will also work inside of a container.

For example, you can use mpstat. This command will measure utilization every ten seconds:

```
mpstat -u 10
```

It will print out a report every ten seconds, detailing how often the CPU was idle,  what it was doing when it wasn't idle, and a timestamp. If you want a more frequent report, you can change the '10' parameter.

Comment: Is there any way to do using cat /sys/fs/cgroup

Comment: You technically can, but they're measured in ticks of usage, not percent over a recent timespan, so you'd need to find a way to convert it.